# using OpenGL to assign color to pixels

Tags: opengl, colors, pixel

I have a NxM dimension of array. The data type is double and their values can  range from 0.000001 to 1.0. I want to display them using OpenGL with colors in NxM pixels, e.g. 0.0001 ~ 0.0005 will be red, 0.0005 ~ 0.001 will be light red, like a picture with legend for different ranges.

I thought I should use texture for efficiency, but I do not quite understand how to match the value in the array to the texture. Do I first need to define a texture like a legend? How will the value in the array use the color in the texture?

Or should I first create a color lookup table and use glDrawPixels? How to define the color table in this case?

Following the approach posted by @Josef Rissling, I defined a legend, then each pixel gets an index in the legend position. I currently use glDrawPixels(). I suppose each legend position contains R, G, B value. How should I set the glPixelTransfer and glPixelMap()? The code I pasted below give me just a black screen.

```
GLuint legend_image[1024][3];  // it contains { {0,0,255}, {0,0,254}, ...}

// GL initialization;
glutInit(&c, &argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(width_, height_);
glutCreateWindow("GPU render");
// allocate buffer handle
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer_obj_);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, buffer_obj_);
// allocate GPU memory
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, width_ * height_, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
// request a CUDA C name for this buffer
CUDA_CALL(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&res_, buffer_obj_, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone));

glPixelTransferi(GL_MAP_COLOR, true);
glPixelMapuiv(GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_I, 1024, legend_image[0]);

glutDisplayFunc(draw_func);
glutIdleFunc(idle_func);
glutMainLoop();

void idle_func()
{
    // cuda kernel to do calculation, and then convert to pixel legend position which is pointed by dev_ptr.
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &res_, 0);
    unsigned int* dev_ptr;
    size_t size;
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&dev_ptr, &size, res_);
    cuda_kernel(dev_ptr);
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &res_, 0);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void draw_func()
{
    glDrawPixels(width_, height_, GL_COLOR_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// some cleanup code...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention which language and which openGL version you are using...

The effiency depends on what kind of function you use for the mapping, texture lookups are not cheap. Especially if you are not using a texture as array already (than you have to copy the data first).

But for your mapping example: 
You can create a legend texture (in which you applied your non-linear color space) that will allow you to map from your value range to color by pixel offset (where the mapped color value lies). The general case would be than for a pseudo shader:

```
map(value)
{
    pixelStartPosition, pixelEndPosition;
    pixelRange = pixelEndPosition - pixelStartPosition;
    valueNormalizer = 1.0 / (valueMaximum - valueMinimum);
    pixelLegendPosition = pixelStartPosition + pixelRange * ( (value-valueMinimum) * valueNormalizer);
    return pixelLegendPosition;
}
```

Say you have a legend texture with 2000 pixels in the range from 0 to 1999 with a value from 0 to 1:

```
pixelStartPosition=0
pixelEndPosition=1999
pixelRange = pixelEndPosition - pixelStartPosition // 1999
valueNormalizer = 1.0 / (valueMaximum - valueMinimum) // 1.0
pixelLegendPosition = pixelStartPosition + pixelRange * ( (value-valueMinimum) * valueNormalizer) 
// 0 + 1999 * ( (value-0) * 1 ) ===> 1999 * value
```

If you need to transmit the array data to a texture, there are several ways to do so - but it depends on your version/language mainly, but glTexImage2D is a good direction.

Comment: I am using C++. and I doing CUDA/OpenGL interoperation. So the value in the CUDA kernel calculated, will be converted to a pixel legend position (like you posted). And the next step is to use this position to get the color